# Median of three values

Tags: c

I am trying to write a C program that takes 3 values as function arguments and returns the median. The program was running quite well - until I realized it did not work with same values twice or more.
For examples if the input is 1,2,3 - I get 2 ,correct median but if the input is 1,2,1 or 1,1,1 ..The loop keeps repeating from beginning .I think I have the logic right but there must be some tiny error which I am making .

My attempt :

```
int median(int firstInt,int secondInt, int thirdInt) {

   if (secondInt>firstInt && secondInt>thirdInt || 
      thirdInt>firstInt && firstInt>secondInt) {
      printf("The median value is %d\n", firstInt);
   }
   if (firstInt>secondInt && secondInt>thirdInt || 
      thirdInt>secondInt && secondInt>firstInt) {
      printf("The median value is %d\n", secondInt);
   }
   if (firstInt>thirdInt && thirdInt>secondInt || 
      secondInt>thirdInt && thirdInt>firstInt) {
      printf("The median value is %d\n", thirdInt);
   }
}

void main() {

   int count = 100; 
   int firstInt,secondInt,thirdInt;

   while(count--) 
   {

      printf("Enter first Integer : "); 
      scanf("%d", &firstInt); 
      printf("Enter second Integer : "); 
      scanf("%d", &secondInt); 
      printf("Enter third Integer : ");
      scanf("%d", &thirdInt); 
      median(firstInt, secondInt, thirdInt); //calling

   }
}

Input : 1,2,1
Output :Enter first integer : // WHY is this happening?
```

Comment: First off, do you know what has higher precedence, `&&` or `||`?

Comment: Unable to reproduce

Comment: The word please does not appear in the code at all. Can't help if not seeing actual code or problem.

Comment: First of all, you have to learn how to indent your code and how to use `else` in the `if` command. If the first test you do with your `if` results `true`, the others should not have been tested (in this case). In your code, the program will pass by all the `if`s unnecessarily.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it now . I donot know which as higher precedence, but I am assuming and has more than or

Comment: What compiler are you using? Besides, it seems your `median` function has a wrong logic.

Comment: I am using online compiler.

Comment: Have you done the logic by hand to make sure it's right? For example with median(1,1,1) `1>1 && 1>1 || 1>1 && 1>1` is false so the first thing won't print, `1>1 && 1>1 || 1>1 && 1>1` is false so the second thing won't print, and `1>1 && 1>1 || 1>1 && 1>1` is false so the third thing won't print.

Comment: thanks for the correction immibis , I changed the > to >= and it works now. It shows how important logic is rather than just writing lines !

Comment: "It shows how important logic is rather than just writing lines" - one of the wisest statements I've ever heard :-)

Answer (score 11):

The *first* thing you should do is decide what your function is meant to do. Its signature and name suggest it's supposed to *return* the median but the code actually *prints* it (and, if it just prints it, it should probably have a `void` return type).

The printing is probably best left to the caller, leaving the function to just calculate and return the median. This makes it a much more general-purpose function.

In any case, it's the use of `>` rather than `>=` which is causing your problem here since data sets where two or more numbers are identical will tend to result in none of the `if` statements being true.

A "cleaner" solution (in my opinion) would just be to cover all of the six possibilities in turn:

```c
int median (int a, int b, int c) {
    if ((a <= b) && (b <= c)) return b;  // a b c
    if ((a <= c) && (c <= b)) return c;  // a c b
    if ((b <= a) && (a <= c)) return a;  // b a c
    if ((b <= c) && (c <= a)) return c;  // b c a
    if ((c <= a) && (a <= b)) return a;  // c a b
    return b;                            // c b a
}
```

Note that I've used `<=` here, simply because it more closely aligns the conditions with the sequences shown in the comment. The important thing is to use an inclusive comparison operator, whether `>=` *or* `<=`, rather than an exclusive one like `>`.

You could even refactor out the comparison so that the code is more readable, with something like:

```c
static int is_ordered(int x, int y, int z) {
    return (x <= y) && (y <= z);
}
int median (int a, int b, int c) {
    if (is_ordered(a, b, c)) return b;
    if (is_ordered(a, c, b)) return c;
    if (is_ordered(b, a, c)) return a;
    if (is_ordered(b, c, a)) return c;
    if (is_ordered(c, a, b)) return a;
    return b;                          // Only one left is c, b, a.
}
```

I wouldn't initially worry about the extra function calls involved here unless you want to call it many, *many* times per second. Even then, you may find the compiler is smart enough to inline the function anyway. My general advice is to optimise for readability first, *then* worry about performance only if it becomes an issue.

---

There is, of course, another option (there almost always is).

Since there are only three values, it's a simple matter to sort them and just return the middle one. It doesn't have to be a complicated sort since you can just use an unrolled bubble sort created from a few conditionals. The code for doing that is shown below:

```c
int median (int a, int b, int c) {
    // Unrolled bubble sort, then return middle one.

    if (a > b) { int t = a; a = b; b = t; }
    if (b > c) { int t = b; b = c; c = t; }
    if (a > b) { int t = a; a = b; b = t; }

    return b;
}
```

Personally, I don't think that's as readable as the earlier code but, if you prefer it, it's certainly functional.

Answer (score 1):

In generic C++ code, the use of the smaller-than operator is typically preferred.

This could result in something like:

```
template<typename T>
T median(T a, T b, T c)
{
   return (b<a)
              ?   (b<c)  ?  (c<a) ? c : a  :  b
              :   (a<c)  ?  (c<b) ? c : b  :  a;
}
```

Comment: Re "the use of the smaller-than operator is typically preferred", do you have a citation for this? I know people implemented the "swathe" of comparison operators based on some combination of two (to minimise complex checks) but that could equally have been `>` and `==` rather then `<` and `==`. I suspect that, even if this *were* so at some point, it's been made irrelevant with the introduction of the three-way comparison operator with its reversing/rewriting rules.